# C - Reading string between two numbers

Tags: c++, string

I have a file, for example:

```
23423 923742 stackoverflow 123
1292 19432 overflow stack 123 9331
```

I read that data now as:

```
sscanf(data,"%d %d %s %d", ...);
```

And that works fine until there is string with space in it (2nd line for example, number 123 is also included in string).
Of course I could search from end of line for first space and read string to that point, but that sound too complicated for something so simple...
Does anyone have any better idea or is there anything built in to help me?

Comment: It's not that simple. First row, you have 4 fields. 2nd row, you have 6 fields. Field 4 can be either string or integer. That does not map well to a simple scanf()

Comment: Title says C, tag says C++, code snippit shows `sscanf`... so please pick a language. They are not the same and "natural" solutions in one may not work in the other.

Comment: For getting a pattern, each line should have equal number of fields and order too. Otherwise, you need to read the entire line into one string, then do strtok to parse individual fields as tokens

Comment: Do you have any control over the file format? That is, can you change the format so that it is simpler to process it the way you want to?

Comment: I solved the problem by counting spaces before reading. 2nd_space+1 =string start, last_space=string end, and last_space+1=number.